# Pascal : What's the difference between random(); and random;

Tags: random, pascal, parentheses

Whether I use `random` or `random()`, I 'seem' to get the same results. Now, coming from a Python background, using `random()` seems more natural and convenient to me, but I've seen `random` being used plenty a times.

Neither statements produce a hint or a warning using FPC's appropriate flags.

So, is there a difference, and if yes, what is it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no difference. Pascal doesn't require the parentheses when calling functions without parameters. You can use them to make your code more clear when reading it, but they're entirely optional.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your insight! (Will accept when it's allowed!)

Comment: In FPC in some cases adding() can disambiguate between assigning a function that returns a functiontype to a functiontype-variable, and assigning calling the function and assigning that to the functiontype-variable.

Comment: That used to be true in Delphi's compiler as well, but now it's much better at figuring out from context which you're trying to do. But the poster didn't mention a specific compiler.

Comment: Oh, thanks for the information, I had expected such a behavior (given that it's what we get in Python) but couldn't quite understand so as my Pascal skills & needs don't reach using functions in variables!

Answer (score 1):

since i have seen a bit of scala code ,so here i am guessing.

There is a no difference between random and random(),If function takes  no parameters,
you can omit parenthesis  in the code.